# Add attribute to block: Autocad API VB.net

Tags: vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am using below code to add attribute to certain block,

But it does not work, I am not getting what exactly going wrong and there is no error.

```
Public Class addattribute
    Public Function addnewattribute()


        Dim attdef As New AttributeReference
        Dim templatepath As String = "C:\Users\sesa388372\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SchneiderMacros\Wtemplate.DWG"
        Dim db As Database = New Database
        db.ReadDwgFile(templatepath, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, False, "")
        Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
            attdef.SetDatabaseDefaults(db)
            attdef.Tag = "Cell location"
            attdef.TextString = "AAA"


            Dim bt As BlockTable = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite)
            Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite)
            For Each objid As ObjectId In btr
                If objid.ObjectClass.Name = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
                    Dim blkref As BlockReference = tr.GetObject(objid, OpenMode.ForWrite)
                    If blkref.Name = "TB-D-ATTR" Then

                        blkref.AttributeCollection.AppendAttribute(attdef)

                    End If
                End If
            Next

            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(attdef, True)
            tr.Commit()

        End Using

        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the main problem are the BlockReference location and that you did not save the file. I made some adjusts on the code, but could not fully test it, check the comments below.

```
Public Sub addnewattribute() ' don't you mean define as Sub?
  Dim templatepath As String = "C:\Users\sesa388372\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SchneiderMacros\Wtemplate.DWG"
  ' you must dispose this side database, the 'using' will take care of it
  Using db As Database = New Database(False, True) ' specify the parameters
    db.ReadDwgFile(templatepath, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite, False, "")
    db.CloseInput() ' this should help the Save() method
    Using tr As Transaction = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
      Dim bt As BlockTable = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite)
      Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace), OpenMode.ForWrite)
      For Each objid As ObjectId In btr
        If objid.ObjectClass.Name = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
          Dim blkref As BlockReference = tr.GetObject(objid, OpenMode.ForWrite)
          If blkref.Name = "TB-D-ATTR" Then
            ' define this variable inside the loop, you cannot reuse it
            Dim attdef As New AttributeReference
            attdef.SetDatabaseDefaults(db)
            attdef.Tag = "Cell location"
            attdef.TextString = "AAA"
            attdef.SetAttributeFromBlock(blkref.BlockTransform) ' adjust the location
            blkref.AttributeCollection.AppendAttribute(attdef)
            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(attdef, True)
          End If
        End If
      Next
      tr.Commit()
    End Using
    'Return Nothing ' in this case, a Sub (instead function) should be better
    db.Save() ' did you miss to save changes?
  End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried db.save() command but it gives error,                                        An exception of type 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception' occurred in AcdbMgd.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: eFileInternalErr  @Augusto Goncalves

Comment: `Database.Save` is not implemented. Use `Database.SaveAs` instead.

Comment: @PankajPotdar, I have edit my code, added a call to CloseInput() right after ReadDwgFile() call.

Comment: The `ReadDwgFile` with the `FileShare` parameter is obsolete, according to the documentation. You should use the one with a `FileOpenMode` parameter.

Comment: @ Augusto Goncalve , I tried using db.closeinput(true) and db.closeinput (false), but error is same "eFileInternalErr" at db.save()

Comment: @ Maxence can you please tell me more about FileOpenMode, Is this another method to open side database of drawing?

Comment: @PankajPotdar, I would suggest you save with a different name, see this code sample: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/04/batch-process-in-memory-1.html

Comment: Cracked.. thanks  @AugustoGoncalves it worked!!, now but out of curiosity we can not use db.save command? and one more thing though it added attribute its not displayed in drawing how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're trying to add an AttributeDefinition to a Block Reference.

You'll need to add the AttributeDefinition to the BlockTableRecord and then update the AttributeReference in the BlockReference.

See here for more info: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/changing-block-definition-of-an-block-reference.html

Also, are you running the ATTSYNC command after to make sure your block reference is displaying correctly?

Comment: I did not get you.. In my case blcokreference already has some attributes I need to add new attribute to it. Do I ned to create attribute definition?

Comment: @Miiir, despite the variable name is 'attdef', the variable type is AttributeReference

Comment: @PankajPotdar, yes, you need to add the AttributeDefinition first.