# Unable to Update Attributes in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, autocad

The following code doesn't update the attributes and unable to ascertain why my attributes not updating.

The case statements definitely being hit so for some reason my changes aren't being committed to the database.

```
Database db = new Database(false, true);
        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            db.ReadDwgFile(fileName, System.IO.FileShare.Read, false, "");
            db.CloseInput(true);
            BlockTable bt = tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTable;
            BlockTableRecord acBlkTblRec = tr.GetObject(bt[BlockTableRecord.PaperSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;
            foreach (ObjectId id in acBlkTblRec)
            {
                DBObject obj = tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockReference blkRef = obj as BlockReference;
                if (blkRef != null)
                {
                    AttributeCollection attCol = blkRef.AttributeCollection;
                    foreach (ObjectId objID in attCol)
                    {
                        DBObject dbObj = tr.GetObject(objID, OpenMode.ForWrite) as DBObject;

                        AttributeReference acAttRef = dbObj as AttributeReference;
                        switch (acAttRef.Tag)
                        {
                            case "DRAWINGTITLE1":
                                acAttRef.TextString = controllerName;
                                break;
                            case "DATE1":
                            case "DATE4":
                            case "XX_XX_XX":
                                acAttRef.TextString = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                                break;
                            case "DW1":
                            case "CK1":
                            case "XXX":
                                acAttRef.TextString = userSuffix;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
```

Comment: Haven't used this but a) FileShare.Read ?? and b) CloseInput(true) - _"If bCloseFile is true, **the drawing file will be closed** when it has been fully read."_

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325210/add-attribute-to-block-autocad-api-vb-net

Comment: aren't you missing save the file?

Comment: @stuartd thanks for the link. Now realise need to save to database which wasn't doing

Comment: Yes @augustogoncalves I hadn't saved to database. New to the Autocad API